# R. Convert TimeStamp column from DataFrame to Date Format column

Tags: r, date, vector, type-conversion, timestamp

I have got a question.

There are a column with timestamp records like '1643410273'(summary more than 1.2M records). How can I transform it into Date format?

I created this code (R Language):

```
mydata <- read.csv("summary_dataset.csv")
unique(mydata$Callsign)
flight <- mydata[mydata$Callsign == "AFR228",]
AltitudeValue <- flight$Altitude
UTC_Timestamp <- flight$Timestamp
Flight_Date <- vector()

for (i in 1:length(UTC_Timestamp)){
  Flight_Date[i]=as.POSIXct(UTC_Timestamp[i], origin='1970-01-01', tz="UTC")
}

Flight_Date
```

But, in result, vector Flight_Date was filled Timestamp records. What's wrong?

Comment: `flight$Flight_Date <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(as.numeric(flight$Timestamp), origin='1970-01-01', tz="UTC"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the `Timestamp` column first to numeric, change it to `POSIXct` format by passing `origin` and extract only the date from it.

```
flight$Flight_Date <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(as.numeric(flight$Timestamp), 
                              origin='1970-01-01', tz="UTC"))
```

Example -

```
as.POSIXct(1643410273, origin='1970-01-01', tz="UTC")
#[1] "2022-01-28 22:51:13 UTC"

as.Date(as.POSIXct(1643410273, origin='1970-01-01', tz="UTC"))
#[1] "2022-01-28"
```